Solving $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\frac32+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)}dx$
I found the following integral on Instagram and found it rather interesting so I gave it a shot. However, I got stuck in the middle and needed some guidance to continue.$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\frac32+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)}dx$$
Using properties of the gamma function:
$$\Gamma(\frac32+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)=\Gamma(1+\frac12+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)$$
And we know: $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)\land\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z-1)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$
$$\implies\Gamma(1+\frac12+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)=(\frac12+x)\Gamma(\frac12+x)\Gamma(1-(\frac12+x))=(\frac12+x)\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi(\frac12+x))}$$
$$\implies \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi x)}{\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi x}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\cos(\pi x)}{2x+1}dx\implies^{2x+1\to x}\implies\frac{\sqrt e}{\pi}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac x2}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{x}dx$$
$$^{\frac x2\to x}\implies\int_{\frac12}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(\pi x)}{x}dx$$
And here I get stuck. My attempt so far involved trying to convert the integral into a more workable form, but I can't figure out how to continue doing this. I would appreciate any hints to move forward. Thanks

Wolfram Alpha gives the same numeric result for both and doesn't give an exact form for either.

That numeric result is $0.08664351250630259$.

I am under the assumption that this has a closed-form solution. I say this because every other integral posted by this account has a closed-form solution and I expect this to be no different.

The integral equals $$\frac{\sqrt e}\pi\int_{\frac12}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(\pi x)}{x}dx= \frac{\sqrt e}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac12}\frac{e^{(1-\pi i)x}}xdx-\frac{\sqrt e}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac12}\frac{e^{(1+\pi i)x}}xdx $$ and has a closed form with the Ei function, but trying to get an integrand of $\frac{e^x}x$ makes the bounds a complex number times $\infty$

Mathematica indicates $$\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)}, e^{-x}=\frac{2 \cos(\pi x)}{2 \pi x+\pi}, e^{-x}$$ and $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 \cos(\pi x)}{2 \pi x+\pi}, e^{-x}, dx=\frac{i \sqrt{e}}{2 \pi} \left(\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2} i (i+\pi)\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{2} i (-i+\pi)\right)-2 i \pi\right)$$ which perhaps can be proven by using $$\cos(\pi x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-i \pi x}+\frac{1}{2} e^{i \pi x}$$ and the definition of the exponential integral function $\text{Ei}(x)$.

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ei{Ei}$The integral equals $$\frac{\sqrt e}\pi\int_{\frac12}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\sin(\pi x)}{x}dx= \frac{i\sqrt e}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac12}\frac{e^{(1-\pi i)x}}xdx-\frac{i\sqrt e}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac12}\frac{e^{(1+\pi i)x}}xdx$$
Substituting gives:
$$\frac{i\sqrt e}{2\pi}\int_{(\pi i-1)\infty}^{\frac{\pi i-1}2}\frac{e^x}xdx-\frac{i\sqrt e}{2\pi}\int_{-(\pi i+1)\infty}^{-\frac{\pi i+1}2}\frac{e^{x}}xdx$$
The antiderivative of $\frac{e^x}x$ is the exponential integral function and using $\Ei(-(\pi i+1)\infty)=-\pi i,\Ei((\pi i-1)\infty)=\pi i$, found computationally, we finally get:
$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\frac32+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)}dx=\frac{i\sqrt e}{2\pi}\Ei\left(\frac{\pi i-1}2\right)-\frac{i\sqrt e}{2\pi}\Ei\left(-\frac{\pi i+1}2\right)+\sqrt e}$$

Is there a form in terms of the trigonometric integrals?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\frac32+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)}dx& = \frac{\sqrt e}{\pi}  \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} \sin (\pi x)}{x} d x \\
& = \frac{\sqrt e}{\pi} \Im\left(\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} e^{\pi x i}}{x}\right) d x \\
& = \frac{\sqrt e}{\pi} \Im \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} \frac{e^{(\pi i-1) x}}{x} d x \\
& = \frac{\sqrt e}{\pi}  \Im\left[\operatorname{Ei}((\pi i-1) x)\right]_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt e}{\pi} \Im\left[\pi i-\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{\pi i-1}{2}\right)\right] \\
& = \sqrt e-\frac{\sqrt e}{\pi} \Im\left[\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{\pi i-1}{2}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where Ei(.) is the Exponential Integral .


After @Тyma Gaidash's answer and question in comment.
We are very close to trigonometric integrals since
$$\text{Ei}\left(\frac{i \pi}{2}-\epsilon\right)
-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{i \pi }{2}-\epsilon\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \,(a_n-b_n)\,\epsilon^n$$ where the coefficients are given by recurrence relation
$$a_{n+2}=\frac{2 n a_n+i (n+1) (\pi a_{n+1}-1)}{2 (n+1) (n+2)^2}$$where
$$a_0=\text{Ci}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+i\,\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)+\frac{i \pi }{2}\qquad a_1=\frac 2 \pi\qquad a_2=\frac{\pi +2 i}{\pi ^2}$$
and
$$b_{n+3}=\frac{(n+1) \left(\pi  b_{n+1}+2 i (n+2)^2 b_{n+2}\right)-2 i n b_n}{\pi  (n+1) (n+2) (n+3)}$$
$$b_0=\text{Ci}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-i\, \text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\frac{i \pi}{2}\qquad b_1=\frac 2 \pi\qquad b_2=\frac{\pi -2 i}{\pi ^2}$$
If $c_n=(-1)^n \,(a_n-b_n)$, the first coefficients are
$$\left\{i \left(2 \text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\pi \right),0,\frac{4 i}{\pi
   ^2},-\frac{8 i}{3 \pi ^2},\frac{i \left(\pi ^2-8\right)}{\pi ^4},-\frac{4 i \left(\pi
   ^2-24\right)}{15 \pi ^4},\frac{i \left(384-48 \pi ^2+\pi ^4\right)}{18 \pi ^6}\right\}$$
This gives for the definite integral
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\frac32+x)\Gamma(\frac12-x)}\,dx$$
$$2 \pi \left(\frac{I}{\sqrt{e}}-1\right)=-2\, \text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)-\pi+\sum_{n=2}^\infty d_n\,\left(\frac{\epsilon }{\pi}\right)^n$$  the first coefficients being
$$\left\{-4,\frac{8 \pi }{3},8-\pi ^2,\frac{4\pi  \left(\pi ^2-24\right)}{15} ,\frac{-384+48 \pi ^2-\pi ^4}{18} \right\}$$
Using the above terms with $\epsilon=\frac 12$ gives
$$I\sim \sqrt{e} \left(-\frac{\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{\pi
   }+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1920-1968 \pi ^2+4157 \pi ^4}{11520 \pi ^7}\right)$$  which is $\color{red} {0.0866}20$.
